# Asp.Net MVC5 Project Admin Area Route - Error Routing Controller ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

MVC5 project I created the area for the admin panel.
I got a problem.

There are ProductController and ListActionResult on the **front of the site**.

And.

There are ProductController and ListActionResult in the **admin panel**.

Now...

I am going to admin panel ProductController and ListActionResult.**(www.xxxxxxxxx.com/Admin/Home/List)**

But the project open on its front page. **(www.xxxxxxxxx.com/Home/List)**

**Page I want to open >> www.xxxxxxxxx.com/Admin/Home/List**

**But this opening page >> www.xxxxxxxxx.com/Home/List**

*It does not change the page address.*

But it going controller.

What could be the problem.

Below are the route information.

AdminAreaRegistration.cs;

```
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    { 
        public override string AreaName 
        { 
            get 
            { 
               return "Admin"; 
            } 
        } 

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context ) 
        { 
            context.MapRoute( 
               "Admin_default", 
               "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
               new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
               new[] { "Projem.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" } 
             ; 
   }
```

RouteConfig.cs;

```
    public class RouteConfig 
    { 
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes ) 
        { 
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" ); 
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes( ); 
            routes.MapRoute( 
               name: "Default", 
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
               namespaces: new[] { "Projem.Web.Controllers" } 
             ; 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change in RegisterArea method like this.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = "" },
            new[] { "Projem.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: i think you do not register your area in global.asax file. you can register area in global.asax file in Application_Start() method. write below line 
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

Comment: "Projem.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" namespace of area is right?

Comment: Yes right!

Admin Panel Test Controller Book Action working. No problem.

TestController and BookAction is not on the front of the site.

Only the panel.
That's why it works.